# How to use awk to cut out a string ="" in different columns per line

Tags: bash, awk, cut

So I have 1000s of lines where it looks like below:

`A="10" B="20" C="20"
    A="10" B="20" C="20"
    A="10" C="20" D="20"
    C="10" D="20" A="20"`

I want to pull out all the C="X" , also I may possible need to find what A="X" also at some point.  The above is a shorten sample, but it maybe easily dozens of columns and it is all over the place.

I think awk would be better than cut, but haven't quite figured out the best way to pull that information.

Thanks

Comment: For the `C="X"` example, what should the output look like?

Comment: Can you explain why do you think `awk` is *better* than `cut` here? Have you also searched for other alternatives? Can you show what you have tried so far? Did you at least tried to get familiar with `awk` and even `cut` ?

Comment: I would be ok with C="X" or just "X".

Comment: @hek2mgl - i only know how to use cut with -d and -c , which in this case would be hard since I am not able to determine the column per line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `grep` will do:

```
grep -o 'C="[0-9]*"' file
```

Output:

```
C="20"
C="20"
C="20"
C="10"
```

Comment: You just blew my mind, I didn't even think of that path.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^(A=|C=)\"/)s=s?s FS $i:$i; print s}' file  
A="10" C="20"
A="10" C="20"
A="10" C="20"
C="10" A="20"
```

Comment: I just tried it, works great.  Ah I have a much better understanding of how to pull that type of data!.

Answer (score 0):

Only a sed implementation is missing. Here it is:

```
sed -n 's/.*C="*\([0-9]*\)".*/\1/p' file
```

It returns only the Xs

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind for next time also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `awk` possibility.

```
awk '{
     delete a
     for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
       a[substr($i, 1, 1)] = int(substr($i, 4))
     print a["A"], a["C"]
}' file
```

This gathers all the letter/value pairs, storing the values as actual integers (without quotes) in an associative array keyed by the letter. This allows you to print them out any way you want. For example, you can print them in alphabetical order no matter what the original order (although the original order is forgotten).